# Run same Python script multiple times with different values set in a column

Tags: python, loops

I would need to run the same python script multiple times with different values set in the date and year column and generate multiple dataframe so that I can append the data together to show the trend.

Process:

1. Run the whole script for date= '01Jan2022' and year='2022' and generate df1;
2. Run the whole script again for date = '11Jan2022' and year='2022' and generate df2;
   .
   .
   .
3. Append df1, df2, df3... together to create the final df.

How to create a loop to run multiple times with different values in date and year?

Thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and where you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you have python script that runs against date parameter, and you want to run it multiple times with different values of date, so i think you can encapsulate the function that generates the output and make the for loop on it, as in the example:

```
def generate_output(date):
    /// logic of your script
date_values = [val1, val2, val3]
dfs = list()
for index, date_val in enumerate(date_values):
    dfs.append(generate_output(date_values[index]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! You are correct that I already have my script ready. I tried the method and received error code "NameError: name 'Date' is not defined. I used cur.execute to use my SQL query, and it cause this error message.